# React.js - Using context to call a component's method anywhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My application consists of several pages. Every page has a `ToastContainer` component and some other component that behaves as a small single-page application (in this case, `Job`):

[image]

Note that `Job` and `ToastContainer` are siblings.

I have set up some basic [toasts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/toasts/) in my application and I want to be able to call a method on `ToastContainer` called `pushToast(...)` from anywhere in my application, since many child components of make AJAX calls that return feedback/responses to the user and it is not feasible to pass down a toast method into every component that I have.

```
const ToastContext = React.createContext(); //???

export default class ToastContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      toastList: [],
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      
      <div id="toast-container" className="toast-container position-absolute top-0 end-0 p-3" style={{'zIndex': 999}}>

        {this.state.toastList.map(toast => (

          <Toast .../>

        ))}

      </div>
    )
  }

  pushToast = (title, time, content) => //HOW CAN I MAKE THIS METHOD ACCESSIBLE TO JOB AND ITS CHILDREN?
  {

    var newToast = {
      title: title,
      time: time,
      content: content,
    }

    this.setState({
      toastList: [...this.state.toastList, newToast]
    })
  }
```

I think what I need to use are [React.js contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), but I don't know where to define the context and if the other components (such as `Job`) will have access to it. I need to somehow send `pushToast` defined in `ToastContainer` into every component (globally) so that I can call it from anywhere I want

Comment: state of `ToastContainer` must be global? (`state.toastList`)

Comment: Yes -- If the state of `ToastContainer` was global, I could push toasts to it. It would be ideal if I could just called ToastContainer.pushToast(...) though. Very surprised this framework doesn't have something like this

Comment: If toast is on all pages, why not put it in router page? Avoids using context, as just doing it all in that page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by router page -- my application is Laravel + React

Comment: Do you use create-react-app or nextjs?

Comment: If you are not using nextjs, then when you navigate through pages, you should have a routing bage like this.https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Off you are using nextjs. You would have a main app file, that if you put a layout round could do the same. But this has to be for all pages if you don't change render per route

Answer (score 0):

way to solve this problem could be creating a context wrapper, first of all, you have to create a file that represents the `ToastContextWrapper` then creates a wrapper component that holds the state of your toats and pushToast function and then passes it to the context provider and wraps whole your project (because you want to access it from everywhere you want, otherwise you can consider a specific scope).

let me give you an example by code:

***ToastContextWrapper.jsx:***

```
export const ToastContext = React.createContext(undefined);

export default function ToastContextWrapper({ children }) {
  const [toastData, setToastData] = React.useState([]);
  const pushToast = (newToast) => setToastData((prev) => [...prev, newToast]);

  return (
    <ToastContext.Provider
      value={{
        value: toastData,
        pushToast,
      }}>
      {children}
    </ToastContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

then you have to wrap your project by this component:

***index/App.js:***

```
const Child = () => {
  const toastContext = React.useContext(ToastContext);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{JSON.stringify(toastContext.value)}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => toastContext.pushToast('BlahBlah ')}>
        Call ToastData!
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <ToastContextWrapper>
      <Child />
    </ToastContextWrapper>
  );
}
```

in this way by using ToastContext you have access to the values, the first one is toast state, and the seconds one is pushToast.

Comment: I don't have a master App component, instead each page has two separate components... The ToastContainer and a small application. They need to communicate without having a parent

Comment: @Vranvs at all you have (should) a first level/master component where you wrap your component in it, e.g: `ReactRouter` / `ReactDom.render`